# api result interpretation required on compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/reserved_cores

Tags: google-api, google-cloud-stackdriver, google-cloud-monitoring

I am using this api for retrieving monitoring metrics for reserved core in google

```
https://monitoring.googleapis.com/v3/projects/my-project/timeSeries?pageSize=500&interval.endTime=2020-07-14T21:05:17.278Z&aggregation.alignmentPeriod=3600s&aggregation.perSeriesAligner=align_SUM&filter=metric.type = "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/reserved_cores" AND metric.labels.instance_name="my-instance-name"&pageToken=&interval.endTime=2020-07-14T18:30:06Z&alt=json&aggregation.groupByFields=metric.labels.key
```

I am getting results like this

```
"metricKind": "GAUGE",
      "valueType": "DOUBLE",
      "points": [
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T18:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T18:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 30
          }
        },
        {
          "interval": {
            "startTime": "2020-07-14T17:30:06Z",
            "endTime": "2020-07-14T17:30:06Z"
          },
          "value": {
            "doubleValue": 14
          }
```

I have given aggregate of 3600s in align_sum. I see that for each period i m getting different values of cpu-reserved core ex.
for 1 period i get 30

```
"startTime": "2020-07-14T18:30:06Z",
                "endTime": "2020-07-14T18:30:06Z"
,
              "value": {
                "doubleValue": 30
              }
```

for another period it gives me 14 only

```
{
              "interval": {
                "startTime": "2020-07-14T17:30:06Z",
                "endTime": "2020-07-14T17:30:06Z"
              },
              "value": {
                "doubleValue": 14
              }
```

I am new to this metrics and not able to interpret the results, why the values are coming differently? Also how this metrics would help me in relation to cpu usage time? Kindly help. Thanks

Comment: We do have a [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/monitoring/custom-metrics/reading-metrics) that can help with interpreting metric data.

Comment: Thanks, I had seen that, but this particular api cpu/reserved_cores i dont know what it refers to and also it changes for every time series for the same instance

Comment: I researched the "compute.googleapis.com/instance/cpu/reserved_cores" and found that this value is reported by the hypervisor for the VM and can differ from `agent.googleapis.com/cpu/usage_time`, which is reported from inside the VM. Sampled every 60 seconds. After sampling, data is not visible for up to 240 seconds."